# Javascript random array access speed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have a very simple implementation of Game of Life in javascript and want to find out how to optimize the update loop. Using Chrome's profiler, I'm getting... strange results that I'm not sure how to interpret correctly.

This is the main part of the loop that does pretty much all of the calculations:
(Note that this.texArrs are both initialized as Uint8Arrays AND they are both 2 pixels wider and higher than what I'm actually working with, to avoid having to do any out-of-bounds checks in this loop)

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(this.h * this.w * 4);
var tArr0 = this.texArrs[0];
var tArr1 = this.texArrs[1];
var ylen = this.h;
var xlen = this.w;

for (var y = 1; y < ylen; y++){
  var thisRow = y * xlen,
    prevRow = thisRow - xlen,
    nextRow = thisRow + xlen,
    arrRow = prevRow * 4;

  for (var x = 1; x < xlen; x++) {
    var pIdx = thisRow + x,
      px = tArr0[pIdx],
      arrIdx = arrRow + (x * 4),
      neighborCount = 0,
      prevCol = x - 1,
      nextCol = x + 1;

    // start slow part        
    neighborCount += tArr0[prevRow + prevCol];
    neighborCount += tArr0[prevRow + x];
    neighborCount += tArr0[prevRow + nextCol];
    neighborCount += tArr0[thisRow + prevCol];
    neighborCount += tArr0[thisRow + nextCol];
    neighborCount += tArr0[nextRow + prevCol];
    neighborCount += tArr0[nextRow + x];
    neighborCount += tArr0[nextRow + nextCol];
    // end slow part

    if ((!px && neighborCount === 3) || (px && (neighborCount === 2 || neighborCount === 3))) {
      tArr1[pIdx] = 1;
      arr[arrIdx - 4] = 255;
      arr[arrIdx - 3] = 255;
      arr[arrIdx - 2] = 255;
      arr[arrIdx - 1] = 255;
    } else {
      tArr1[pIdx] = 0;
      arr[arrIdx - 4] = 0;
      arr[arrIdx - 3] = 0;
      arr[arrIdx - 2] = 0;
      arr[arrIdx - 1] = 255;
    }
  }
}
```

Running the profiler for a couple of seconds, this is the result:

[image: Profiler result]

What I don't understand is 
1) why the first 4 neighborCount calls are 10 times faster than the other 4
2) why writing to the arr is so wildly different between indexes

Also how would I, in general, go about finding out why certain calculations are slow/to be avoided? Is that more a general thing, i.e. the basics of how RAM works (in order to optimize the code towards sequential array accesses for example), or would I better off diving into language specifics (i.e. in this case javascript/v8)?

Comment: How big is `tArr0`? How big are `w` and `h`? Is there a reason you're using one array to represent 2 dimensions rather than using a 2-dimensional array (array of arrays)?

Comment: The whole screen size is roughly 1600x900 so quite large. The reason for using a 1-dimensional array is just that I've been using a Uint8Array (which can only store ints).
Edit: actually.... do you think using a 2-dimensional array would be faster in this case? I thought an array of arrays would be a lot slower than just storing ints....?